# Encoding a string in HMAC SHA256

Tags: c, encryption, hmac

How can I encode a string using HMAC SHA256 algorithm? I went through OpenSSL library but didn't find anything valuable. Your suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by *"anything valuable"*? https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/sha.html, https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/hmac.html list various methods

Comment: @MartinR, by anything valuable I mean anything valuable. Does that satisfy you?

Comment: @MartinR The documentation is not very newbie-friendly, but that seems to be the case with other crypto libraries too.  Bouncy Castle is less comprehensive than OpenSSL but its documentation still might as well be ciphertext from a beginner's point of view. :-)

Comment: @JeffreyHantin: Sure. But *"didn't find anything valuable"* is far too broad in my opinion, it does not even indicate *what* OP found and what (s)he tried to make it work.

Comment: What *encoding* are you talking about? HMAC produces an authentication tag which is not reversible, so it isn't an encoding.

Answer (score 11):

[HMAC](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907084840/http://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/hmac.html) and [SHA256](https://web.archive.org/web/20150423055034/http://openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_sha256.html) are separate components in OpenSSL, you'll need to glue them together yourself.  (Note that this uses the shorthand methods for doing everything in one shot with monolithic buffers; incremental processing is more complex.)

```
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

unsigned char* hmac_sha256(const void *key, int keylen,
                           const unsigned char *data, int datalen,
                           unsigned char *result, unsigned int* resultlen)
{
    return HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key, keylen, data, datalen, result, resultlen);
}
```

Even if your input is a string, the result is an arbitrary byte array; if that too needs to be a string then you'll have to apply some other transformation like hexadecimal expansion, Base64 or whatever suits your application.

Comment: your parameter types need work. the data length should be `size_t`, and the `resultlen` should be `unsigned int` and passed by address.

Comment: Good catch on passing `resultlen` by address.  The linked documentation page for HMAC specifies `int` rather than `size_t` for key and data length, and the general lack of type consistency between the buffer pointer and length types is a bit ... confusing, if not an outright code smell.

Comment: If it says `int`, it may be wrong (wouldn't be the first time with OpenSS). I checked the header, and though my OpenSSL is a minor bld old, I would find it odd *that* was changed. I only remembered it because it is the only function I ever ran across that passed three different data lengths with three *different* types: a `size_t`, an `int`, and an `unsigned int`. (the latter by-address). I thought it odd.

Comment: Fyi, from my rig: `unsigned char *HMAC(const EVP_MD *evp_md, const void *key, int key_len, const unsigned char *d, size_t n, unsigned char *md, unsigned int *md_len)`. Like I said, odd. The last one is the one that really matters, and at least that is the same in both yours and mine, so cest'la'vi.

Comment: HMAC and SHA256 links appear dead.

Comment: @chux should be fixed now - found a copy on the Wayback Machine.