# hmac sha256 output length

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, encryption

I'm trying to implement the [AWS V4 signature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) in C, but am failing to calculate the hash in the string to sign. The test example [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html) has:

```
key = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
dateStamp = '20120215'
regionName = 'us-east-1'
serviceName = 'iam'
```

producing

```
kSecret  = '41575334774a616c725855746e46454d492f4b374d44454e472b62507852666943594558414d504c454b4559'
kDate    = '969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d'
kRegion  = '69daa0209cd9c5ff5c8ced464a696fd4252e981430b10e3d3fd8e2f197d7a70c'
kService = 'f72cfd46f26bc4643f06a11eabb6c0ba18780c19a8da0c31ace671265e3c87fa'
kSigning = 'f4780e2d9f65fa895f9c67b32ce1baf0b0d8a43505a000a1a9e090d414db404d'
```

But, for some reason my implementation drops the last few characters of the final element, and I get:

```
kSecret : 41575334774a616c725855746e46454d492f4b374d44454e472b62507852666943594558414d504c454b4559
kDate   : 969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d
kRegion : 69daa0209cd9c5ff5c8ced464a696fd4252e981430b10e3d3fd8e2f197d7a70c
kService    : f72cfd46f26bc4643f06a11eabb6c0ba18780c19a8da0c31ace671265e3c87fa
kSigning    : f4780e2d9f65fa895f9c67b32ce1baf0b0d8a43505a0
```

I'm just using an example for the HMAC_SHA256 calculation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29862424/993874, I can't see what I'm missing. For other calculations (i.e. ones performing requests for my own AWS data etc) I also see that some of the hmac outputs are not 32 characters in length.

Can anyone help address this (and also confirm whether I need to convert all the char arrays to hex strings for AWS requests)?

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                    
#include <string.h>                                                                                                   

#include <openssl/hmac.h> 

void printHex(const char* preface, const char* toPrint) {                                                             

      printf("%s\t: ", preface);                                                                                      
      for(size_t i = 0; i < strlen(toPrint); i++) {                                                                   
            printf("%02x", toPrint[i] & 0xff);                                                                        
      }                                                                                                               
      printf("\n");                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                     


void hmac_sha256(const unsigned char* key,                                                                            
                 const unsigned char* text,                                                                           
                 unsigned char* result) {                                                                             

      unsigned int resultLen;                                                                                         

      HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key, strlen(key), text, strlen(text), result, &resultLen);                                   

}                                                                                                                     


void amazonV4Sign(const unsigned char* accessSecret,                                                                  
                  const unsigned char* amzDate,                                                                       
                  const unsigned char* region,                                                                        
                  const unsigned char* service) {                                                                     

      unsigned char kDate[BUFSIZ];                                                                                    
      unsigned char kRegion[BUFSIZ];                                                                                  
      unsigned char kService[BUFSIZ];                                                                                 
      unsigned char kSigning[BUFSIZ];                                                                                 

      unsigned char kSecret[BUFSIZ];                                                                                  
      sprintf(kSecret, "AWS4%s", accessSecret);                                                                       

      unsigned char request[BUFSIZ];                                                                                  
      sprintf(request, "aws4_request");                                                                               

      hmac_sha256(kSecret, amzDate, kDate);                                                                           
      hmac_sha256(kDate, region, kRegion);                                                                            
      hmac_sha256(kRegion, service, kService);                                                                        
      hmac_sha256(kService, request, kSigning);                                                                       

      printHex("kSecret", kSecret);                                                                                   
      printHex("kDate", kDate);                                                                                       
      printHex("kRegion", kRegion);                                                                                   
      printHex("kService", kService);                                                                                 
      printHex("kSigning", kSigning);                                                                                 

}                                                                                                                     


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {                                                                                    

      unsigned char* key = "wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY";                                                
      unsigned char* dateStamp = "20120215";                                                                          
      unsigned char* regionName = "us-east-1";                                                                        
      unsigned char* serviceName = "iam";                                                                             

      amazonV4Sign(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName);                                                          

      return 0;                                                                                                       
}
```

Comment: Can't you just delete this question and ask "how to calculate hmac sha256 for v4 sig" and self answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop in PrintHex is up to `strlen(toPrint)`.  It's a byte array, not a string, so you cannot use strlen( ).  The loop needs to go up to 32.

Comment: Yep, realised this as soon as I asked the question! Means that the error in my signing process is elsewhere :(.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `strlen` to print the `HMAC` output because byte array may contain `0` byte.

Hence you can use the `md_len` returned by `HMAC` as below to print the byte array.

HMAC returns the length of `md` and syntax is.

```
unsigned char *HMAC(const EVP_MD *evp_md, const void *key,
                      int key_len, const unsigned char *d, int n,
                      unsigned char *md, unsigned int *md_len);
```

Hence use `md_len` to print the array.

```
void printHex(const char* preface, const char* toPrint, int len) {

          printf("%s\t: ", preface);
          for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                printf("%02x", toPrint[i] & 0xff);
          }
          printf("\n");
    }


    int hmac_sha256(const unsigned char* key,
                     const unsigned char* text,
                     unsigned char* result) {

          unsigned int resultLen;

          HMAC(EVP_sha256(), key, strlen(key), text, strlen(text), result, &resultLen);
          printf("%d\n", resultLen);
          return resultLen;
    }


    void amazonV4Sign(const unsigned char* accessSecret,
                      const unsigned char* amzDate,
                      const unsigned char* region,
                      const unsigned char* service) {

          unsigned char kDate[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE] = {0};
          unsigned char kRegion[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE] = {0};
          unsigned char kService[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE] = {0};
          unsigned char kSigning[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE] = {0};

          unsigned char kSecret[BUFSIZ];
          sprintf(kSecret, "AWS4%s", accessSecret);

          printf("%s\n", kSecret);
          unsigned char request[BUFSIZ];
          sprintf(request, "aws4_request");

          int len = hmac_sha256(kSecret, amzDate, kDate);
          printHex("kSecret", kSecret,strlen(kSecret));
          printHex("kDate", kDate,len);
          len = hmac_sha256(kDate, region, kRegion);
          printHex("kRegion", kRegion,len);
          len = hmac_sha256(kRegion, service, kService);
          printHex("kService", kService,len);
          len = hmac_sha256(kService, request, kSigning);

          printHex("kSigning", kSigning,len);

    }
```

Output:

```
kSecret : 41575334774a616c725855746e46454d492f4b374d44454e472b62507852666943594558414d504c454b4559
kDate   : 969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d
kRegion : 69daa0209cd9c5ff5c8ced464a696fd4252e981430b10e3d3fd8e2f197d7a70c
kService        : f72cfd46f26bc4643f06a11eabb6c0ba18780c19a8da0c31ace671265e3c87fa
kSigning        : f4780e2d9f65fa895f9c67b32ce1baf0b0d8a43505a000a1a9e090d414db404d
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I'm a little confused as the examples and outputs from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html differ from online HMAC sha256 calculator results!